# Mark.js makes the page unresponsive when source code of the page is huge

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mark.js

I am using mark.js to highlight the words. It works fine most of the time. But when source code of the page is too big like 55K+ lines it makes the page unresponsive for around 20 seconds.

The page was unresponsive on load, I modified the code so that the script will mark the words after the page was loaded. Now the page loads properly and become unresponsive (for around 20 sec) after that.

Comment: What if someone has come across the issue? Sounds like you'd need to profile Mark.js and figure out how to make it faster.